# tick marks around a Chart.js doughnut?

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

I've seen that there is a ticks configuration option in chart.js, but no matter how I've tried it, it doesn't work.  This was my best attempt:

```
    var chartoverall = document.getElementById("overall").getContext('2d');
        var chartOverall = new Chart(chartoverall, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [
                      "lightblue",
                      "#fff"
                    ],
                    data: [3.2, 1.8],
                    borderColor: '#20457c'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Overall',
                    fontFamily: 'montserrat',
                    fontSize: 18,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    padding: 22
                },
                ticks: {
                    max: 5,
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }
        });
```

Do tick marks work for doughnut and pie charts in Chart.js?  If not, can anyone suggest another solution?  I'm essentially trying to show a rating of 0 to 5 in a doughnut with the color lightblue as the level and then white as the remaining "space" up to 5. I want to label the doughnut so that users can see 1 through 5.